# How to use a generic UITableViewCell in XIB/Storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, generics

```
protocol Configurable {
}

class CoolConfiguration : Configurable {
}

class GenericTableViewCell<T: Configurable>: UITableViewCell  {
}

class CoolTableViewCell : GenericTableViewCell<CoolConfiguration> {
    init(aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        /*  The init() method doesn't work below...so no way to override
            the init properly. Seems like this should work -- GenericTableViewCell is
            _still_ a subclass of UITableViewCell, so what the heck?
        */
        super.init(aDecoder)

        /*  Additionally if you look in CoolTableViewCell.xib, you'll see there is no way 
            to set this class in the class dropdown. So, I can't set the view manually by 
            loading a nib here in the init and I can't set this class as the class to be 
            used in the nib. 
        */
    }
}
```

The comments in the code above explains the issue. Interestingly in the xib I can see the the `GenericTableViewCell` as an option in the class dropdown, which shouldn't even work since the generic `T: Configurable` wouldn't be set.

Likely the answer will be "does not work with objective-c classes," but hoping I'm wrong. Any ideas?